# Xamarin Forms Present a New Page after dismissing Current

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Hi Xamarin developers,

So I have one scenario where user is going from Page A to Page B.

```
await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new PageB());
```

And then from Page B to Page C and in this case Page B should be dismissed first and then Page C should be presented

```
await Navigation.PopModalAsync();
await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new PageC());
```

But With this Code, Page C is never presented, Can You Please help me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But With this Code, Page C is never presented, Can You Please help me what I am doing wrong?

**Solution:**

You should remove `await` from **Page B** as follow:

```
Navigation.PopModalAsync();
Navigation.PushModalAsync(new PageC());
```

If you use the `async/await` asynchronous method, when the `PopModalAsync` method is executed, the interface has returned to the A page. At this time, the `PushModalAsync(new PageC())` method execution will not respond, because this is the method in the B page, and the B interface is After Pop has been released, this method will not work. Therefore, the asynchronous processing method cannot be used in the B page.

**Note：** If *Xamarin Forms (XF)* has an `Activity.finish()` method like *Android*, then the page can be released when the page jumps. This kind of processing in *XF* can only do this as much as possible, although there will be some impact on the visual effect.

Answer (score 1):

When you do PopModalAsync() in a called page, it will fire OnAppearing() event handler in the calling page. To do something after returning from a modal page, you need something like this:

```cs
    public class PageA {
        private bool returnedFromModal = false;

        private async void ShowB_Clicked (object sender, EventArgs e) {
           returnedFromModal = false;
           await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new NavigationPage(new PageB()));
           returnedFromModal = true;
        }

        protected override async void OnAppearing() {
           base.OnAppearing();
           if (returnedFromModal) {
               returnedFromModal = false;
               await Navigation.PushAsync(new PageC());
           }
        }
    }
```